# vanilla JS : module bundled or not

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

Given a set of module-patterned files (a main one, and various subs),

is there a way to detect if modules are bundled together into one single file OR not ? In the last case, I will load manually modules with head script src="" tag added via JS.

Non-bundled files are for development, bundled one is for production use.

EDIT Code is ES 5 !

I don't consider using Browserify, Require or so on...

I assemble my code with (very basic) gulpfiles (using concat, wrap)

someone have an idea ?

Comment: `ES 5 / 2015` ES6 = ES2015, different from ES5. + Your question is unclear

Comment: ES five, not six... "traditional" JS... I want to be able to render in old mobile  WebViews with Apache Cordova, in fact...

Comment: Why do you need to know if the files are bundled or not? Is it so that you know how to include them in your index.html? If yes, you could use something like [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) or [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) and they would handle this for you

Comment: just for helping me during debug work in console (unbundled) and not to load explicitely submodules (bundled version)... thx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bundled file has something in the name to indicate that it is the bundle you can check which script is loaded. For example if you load TopModule.js in development mode and TopLevel.min.js in production you can put this detection in the TopLevel module:

```
var isBundled = (function () {
    var src = '';

    if ('undefined' !== typeof (document.currentScript) && document.currentScript.src) {
        src = document.currentScript.src;
    }
    else {
        (function () {
            var allScriptElements = document.scripts || document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
                    i;

            for (i = 0; i < allScriptElements.length; ++i) {
                if (/(TopLevel(\.min)*)\.js/i.test(allScriptElements[i].src)) {
                    src = allScriptElements[i].src;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }());
    }

    return /\.min\.js/i.test(src);
}());
```

Comment: I hava finally decided to use the technique proposed by @Corina and this works great for me ! Thanks for replies !